# How to pass a parameter to the Spring controller via an URL?

Tags: url, spring-mvc, controller

I want to pass a parameter to the controller and this is what i did :

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getinfoEtab?nomEtab=<c:out value="${activity.nom_etabl}"/>"><c:out value="${activity.nom_etabl}"/></a>
```

The controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getinfoEtab")
    public String getInfoEtablissement(@RequestParam("nomEtab") String nometab,ModelMap model){
         model.addAttribute("etabliss", actservice.FicheEtabl(nometab));
        return "FicheEtablissement";
    }
```

But the controller with this way doesn't get the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getinfoEtab resolving into the url you are trying to reach?
   If your context path is the same as in the url for the page that contains your `<a href>` tag then you don't need ${pageContext.request.contextPath}. You can directly use `<a href="getinfoEtab?nomEtab=`. But if its taking you to the controller don't even bother changing it.
2. Do you see a value in your link where you have `<c:out value="${activity.nom_etabl}"/>`? If you can see the value, then change your code to `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getinfoEtab?nomEtab=${activity.nom_etabl}">`

Comment: 1- the link ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getinfoEtab take me to the controlller 2- the parameter appear in the url but the controller dosen't get it